# how to filter based on key from array using javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

```
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar 22'},
           {'id':'45','foo':'bar'},
           {'id':'46','foo':'area'},
           {'id':'47','foo':'line'}]



var allbars = myArray && myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
      return obj.foo == "bar";
    });
```

After filtering i am able to get

```
 allbars = [{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}]
```

but i need all bars exists in the foo key

```
 Expected output is(in the key foo i have bar, bar22 both are expecting in the output but i can able to get only bar)
    allbars = [{'id':'45','foo':'bar'}, {'id':'73','foo':'bar 22'}]
```

Comment: Try indexOf('bar')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `.includes()` inside the filter condition

```js
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar 22'},
           {'id':'45','foo':'bar'},
           {'id':'46','foo':'area'},
           {'id':'47','foo':'line'}]

var allbars = myArray && myArray.filter(obj => obj.foo.includes("bar"));
    
console.log(allbars)
```

And if you want to make it browser compatible (IE) you may wanna use `.indexOf()`

```js
myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar 22'},
           {'id':'45','foo':'bar'},
           {'id':'46','foo':'area'},
           {'id':'47','foo':'line'}]
           
var allbars = myArray && myArray.filter(obj => obj.foo.indexOf("bar") > -1);
    
console.log(allbars)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String#includes()` or `String#indexOf()` instead of checking equality. Convert both values to lowercase or uppercase if wanting case insensitive match

```
var allbars = myArray && myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
      return obj.foo.includes("bar");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

One can do it using `regular expression` [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test).

```
const pattern = new RegExp('bar', 'i');

var allbars = myArray && myArray.filter(function( obj ) {
      return pattern.test(obj.foo);
    });
```